# How to pass data gathered in PHP to C#?

Tags: c#, php, ms-word, word-template

I've written a webpage (HTML & PHP) where a user can fill in various data into a form (using text-inputs and checkboxes). This data should be added to an already existing .docx template (MS Office Word).

Now I chose PHP because I thought PHPWord would offer the solution to all my needs... but it failed me, and I am not clever enough to adapt to the code make it work somehow. So I looked for another Library that could actually insert tables and images in .docx Templates and found DocX (http://docx.codeplex.com/). But this Library is design for .NET. Now I'm hoping DocX will offer the solution I need or my boss will hang me for wasting time.

So on to the question:
I somehow need to port the data gathered in the webpage from PHP to C#. But I'm not entirely sure how one should go about doing this...

I thought maybe I could transform the data into JSON or XML and somehow read that into my C# program. But I don't understand how to "pass on the data"... do I write to a file and read that file every 5 seconds? Do I create some kind of socket/listener on a certain port? Can I somehow trigger an event in C#? My programming knowlegde is lacking...

Could someone please push me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd go with JSON. You need to serialize your data in PHP. Send them to your C# app and deserialize. The last part is pretty easy. You can just generate classes - http://json2csharp.com/ and use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to get JSON into C# classes.

Comment: The serialization wont we a problem now :) thanks! The sending to C# part is what had me confused the most though. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: I am not experienced in PHP. But if you can output it all in single HTML page, then you can just download it using HttpClient in C# for example..